Extract PPPoE username and password from ONT
My ISP gave me a nokia g-2425g-a ont which I want to put a lan port for using PPPoE so that I can manage the network all from my asus router (TUF-AX3000) The thing is I don't have the PPPoE credentials, so as I read on the internet, I used the tool of "routerpassview" and nothing showed up while loading the config.cfg file. Then I used a python program called "nokia-tool" but at running, this happens and I don't know why:

Also like an old post mentioned here, going to the ONT webpage and trying to change viewtype="password" to "text" didn't do anything, just added a column but blank. Any idea of an alternative to get the PPPoE credentials?

Your exact error is talked about here. Given the nature of the problem you will have to debug the problem and make any necessary adjustments to the script yourself.
